# Text opacity fade when at edge of viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, viewport, opacity

I'm trying to get the .title to fade when it's close to the top/bottom of the screen. I think the problem is with the Jquery document targetting. 
As you can see, the initial fade works perfectly, but the text does not fade when its close to the top/bottom.

You can view the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/niallgrant/pen/GqwmOy).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
    function scrollBanner() {
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('.title').css({
          'top': (scrollPos / 3) + 'px',
          'opacity': 1 - (scrollPos / 100)
        });
        $('.title').css({
          'background-position': 'center ' + (-scrollPos / 200) + 'px'
        });
      });
    }
    scrollBanner();

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".title").delay(1000).hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

```css
/* Parallax base styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

.parallax {
  height: 500px;
  /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  perspective: 300px;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
}
.parallax__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  z-index: 2;
}
/* demo styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* centre the content in the parallax layers */

.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* style the groups
  --------------------------------------------- */

#group1 {
  z-index: 5;
  /* slide over group 2 */
}
#group1 .parallax__layer--base {
  background: rgb(102, 204, 102);
}
#group2 {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}
#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: rgb(123, 210, 102);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="parallax">
  <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">Base Layer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tellus risus, vestibulum non neque ut, consectetur fermentum neque. Nam pharetra tellus pulvinar ante suscipit dapibus. Quisque pharetra libero vel lectus placerat laoreet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You could use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to check how close the element is to the top of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @DiddleDot. Where exactly would I put the .offset() for it to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a closer look at your code and ran it in a jsfiddle and figured out why the scroll event wasn't firing. I changed the `$(document).scroll` to `$('.parallax').scroll` because you're actually scrolling the `.parallax` element not the document. I also moved the call to `scrollBanner()` in the `$(document).ready`

```js
function scrollBanner() {
  $('.parallax').scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.title').css({
      'top': (scrollPos / 3) + 'px',
      'opacity': 1 - (scrollPos / 100)
    });
    $('.title').css({
      'background-position': 'center ' + (-scrollPos / 200) + 'px'
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".title").delay(1000).hide().fadeIn(2000);

  scrollBanner();
});
```

```css
/* Parallax base styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

.parallax {
  height: 500px;
  /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  perspective: 300px;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
}
.parallax__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  z-index: 2;
}
/* demo styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* centre the content in the parallax layers */

.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* style the groups
  --------------------------------------------- */

#group1 {
  z-index: 5;
  /* slide over group 2 */
}
#group1 .parallax__layer--base {
  background: rgb(102, 204, 102);
}
#group2 {
  z-index: 3;
  /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}
#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: rgb(123, 210, 102);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
  <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">Base Layer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tellus risus, vestibulum non neque ut, consectetur fermentum neque. Nam pharetra tellus pulvinar ante suscipit dapibus. Quisque pharetra libero vel lectus placerat laoreet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

With the changes I made your code works. It may not be how you intend it to work, but it's working.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it to work great now.
I'm really appreciative of you taking the time to help me :)